# Additional Parameter in Node Azure Function

Tags: node.js, azure-functions

I am just starting to learn to implement Azure Functions with NodeJS and i am trying to add additional custom parameters to the trigger function
as this is the recommended way for input bindings by Microsoft, but I can't get it to work.

I am getting a 404 Not Found Error.
When I remove the id Object from the function.json, the function works, but the id is undefined.

I tried to call the function with get and id as query param and as post with the { id: 123 } in the body, but with no success.

Can anyone help out?

Thanks in advance.

index.ts

```
const httpTrigger: AzureFunction = async function (
  context: Context,
  req: HttpRequest,
  id: string
): Promise<void> {
  context.log("HTTP trigger function processed a request with id.", id);

  context.res = {
    body: {
      id,
    },
    contentType: "application/json",
  };
};
```

function.json

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "function",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": [
        "get",
        "post"
      ]
    },   
    {
      "authLevel": "function",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "id",
      "methods": [
        "get",
        "post"
      ]
    },   
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "res"
    }
  ],
  "scriptFile": "../dist/respository/index.js"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `Node js` **Azure function** we don’t have an ***Attributes*** and ***Annotations*** so we cannot add additional parameters in azure functions. Attributes are **not supported** by `JavaScript`.

In Azure function [C# class libraries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-class-library) and Java, the `HttpTrigger` attribute is available to configure the function.

You can set the authorization level and allowable HTTP methods in attribute constructor parameters, webhook type, and a route template. For more information about these settings, see [configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook-trigger?tabs=javascript#configuration).

Refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook-trigger?tabs=javascript)

Comment: in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node?tabs=v2#bindings) under "Inputs" it looks like you can configure multiple custom parameters to the function as bindings in the function.json.

Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Hi @belabl, Your understanding where correct but in HTTPTrigger on Nodejs Azure function cannot accept the Additional Attributes and Annotations. So we cannot add any additional parameter. It was possible in C# & java.

Answer (score 0):

**You can do it.** In order to provide additional parameters in your Azure Function, you need to add the `route` attribute in your `function.json` file, so you can access it inside `req.params`.

```json
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": [
        "get",
        "post",
        "put",
        "delete"
      ],
      "route": "repository/{id?}"
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "res"
    }
  ],
  "scriptFile": "../dist/repository/index.js"
}
```